# How to display numbers only at the end of a variable in bash?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

This is actually not my question, someone asked about this in a facebook group but nobody was able to answer it, so there are some variables:

```
x="abcde12345"
y="s'ldfsd[opsk12345"
z="1234sdfsdfafa23456"
```

He wants to show the numbers at the end of those variables, so the end result should be like this:

```
12345
123456
```

The number of digits are vary, it can be 1 to 10 or even 1 to 100000. and it's not always `12345`, it's random. What is the best way to accomplish this ? I've tried `grep -P "[0-9].*[0-9]$"` but it also shows letters between numbers too.

Comment: Is your desired output correct ? From what I understood, wouldn't it be `12345`, `12345`, `23456` instead ?

Comment: And are we talking purely in bash, or simply at a bash prompt, utilizing common Unix tools like grep?

Comment: try `grep -o '[0-9]*$'` instead of `grep -P "[0-9].*[0-9]$"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In bash, you can remove the longest leading substring ending with a non-digit from a variable `$var` using *parameter substitution* `${var##[^0-9]}` or (POSIXly) `${var##[!0-9]}` e.g.

```
$ echo "$x --> ${x##*[^0-9]}"
abcde12345 --> 12345
$ 
$ echo "$y --> ${y##*[^0-9]}"
s'ldfsd[opsk12345 --> 12345
$ 
$ echo "$z --> ${z##*[^0-9]}"
1234sdfsdfafa23456 --> 23456
```

See for example [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

x="abcde12345"
y="s'ldfsd[opsk12345"
z="1234sdfsdfafa23456"


echo $x | grep -o '[0-9]*$'
echo $y | grep -o '[0-9]*$'
echo $z | grep -o '[0-9]*$'
```

Output:

```
12345
12345
23456
```

as per man grep

> ```
> -o, --only-matching
> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on
> a separate output line.
> ```

Comment: You're missing quotes around your variables (try with `x='*'`)

Comment: You can't use `echo` for arbitrary data (try with `x=-Ene`)

Comment: Note that `-o` is a GNU extension and that `grep` searches on every line (try with `x=$'a0\nb1'`.